# simple browser application starting development

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, qtwebkit, layout-engine

I want to create a simple browser but want to use visual studio for making development process easy as I am more comfortable with it.

I tried to find a stable webkit browser layout engine library for NET, but the other projects are either not stable or very old (I wanted to use .NET 4.0). 
Some of them are [Webkit.net](http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/), [Webkit2.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkit2net/)
 I would like to avoid gecko as it still has not full support for html5, untill and unless it comes out to be best option.
Suggest some options to implement.

I am ready to migrate to other languages if better in this context. for example I have seen QT having some webkit browser application.

So my questions are:

1. Which language to prefer (suggest IDE or compiler as well)
2. Which layout engine should be used
3. Which library or framework should be used for graphical interface
4. if platform dependency is considered what are options for windows, Linux or mac.

Comment: do you know any programming language?

Comment: I am pretty comfortable in c# and .net framework, basics of java and c/c++. I can learn other languages too if required. So don't consider language as barrier

Comment: what about .net webbrowser control?

Comment: it uses trident as layout engine which is slow (correct if I am wrong) in rendering as compared to counterparts. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browser_engines#General_information

Comment: what should be the difference between your and existent web browser?

Comment: My custom browser will be used to show specific pages which will be hosted by another module of my application and some differences as no navigation bar and other.